# Python pass in function as argument, print the function name and results

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

If I want to pass a function func1 as argument in another function, but want to return the function name, what shall I do?

let say

```
def func1(x):
    return x**2

def main_function(func1,x):
    .....
    return ___(name of func1),value of func1(x)___
```

which means I want things like:

```
func_name, result = main_function(func1,2)

print(func_name)
func1
print(result)
4
```

Comment: However, note that functions can have more than one identifier, or none. The `__name__` will remain the first one it was assigned to, unless otherwise updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def func1(x):
    return x**2

def main_function(f,x):
    print('f name=', f.__name__)
    print('f value=', f(x))


main_function(func1, 5)
```

output is

```
f name= func1
f value= 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def main_function(f, x):
    return f.__name__, f(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `__name__` to get function name as `str`.

```
def main_function(func, x):
    # do something else
    return func.__name__, func(x)
```